# Hbase Import error

Tags: hbase, hadoop2

I am trying to import a table which was exported from another hbase running on 0.98.4. I exported as below -

```
 hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export 'tblname' /path/
```

And I am trying to import this table which has been put into hdfs using hadoop fs -put. When I run the below import command, it give error -

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver import 'tblname' /hdfs/path

```
2015-06-24 02:19:24,492 ERROR [main] security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:deeshank (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/deeshank/DB/hbase_home/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/deeshank/DB/hbase_home/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1110)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:300)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import.main(Import.java:535)
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue. I am running haddop-2.6.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hdfs://localhost:54310/ is hadoop hdfs address. you can change property in your app or upload your jar on hdfs.

You display ls command of your linux file system and you can use command :

> "hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/"

but hdfs://localhost:9000/ is address of hadoop hdfs file system.

Comment: why is it trying to search the jars in the hdfs? specifically in hdfs://home/..
where should i upload the jars?

Comment: i think u need to set class path of jar files

Comment: can you please assist in details how?

Comment: read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978480/how-to-set-classpath-in-linux-to-let-java-find-jar-file)

Comment: so i need to give the class path of the jar files in the import command?

Comment: Thanks @dilshad it worked perfectly once i copied the jars to hdfs!